# What is wrong with the creation of this JSON file in Java?

Tags: json, file, gson

I created this simple program that creates a `JSON` file into my desktop. The data written on the `JSON` is the data stored in the class `Configuration`.

The issue is that when I execute this program and open the `JSON` file to see if it was copied correctly, this file is empty.

**Main method**

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            Gson gson = new Gson();
            gson.toJson(new Configuration(), new FileWriter("/Users/yo/Desktop/config.json"));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

**Class Configuration**

```
public class Configuration {
    private static final int DB_PORT = 3306;
    private static final String DB_IP = "localhost";
    private static final String DB_NAME = "stock";
    private static final String DB_USER = "root";
    private static final String DB_PASSWORD = "1234";
    private static final int PORT = 5000;
}
```

Why I'm getting an empty file instead that a `JSON` with the data in class `Configuration`? How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

Gson does not serialize **static** members of class.